# Como convertir un String en un Long?

Tags: java

Tengo un objeto llamado operacion, es de tipo `String` y almacena un valor "01"
Dicho valor quiero setearselo a un objeto llamado  nuOperacion que es de tipo `Long`. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
consulta.setNuOperacion(Long.parseLong(datos.getOperacion());
```

Pero me manda el siguiente error:

> Java.lang.NumberFormatException:null

Debe guardarse un 1, pero yo en mi objeto debo de recoger un "01". Como le puedo hacer?

Comment: En la base guardas long y cuando lo consultas pues tendrias que hacer una conversion a como lo necesitas , al ser string pues tu deberias saber como armarlo cuantos ceros agregar a la izquierda

Comment: `datos.getOperacion()` te da nulo, por eso no puede convertirlo a número.

Comment: Como comenta Ruslan @Root93 , el problema es que un valor null no puede ser convertido ya que no es numérico, lo que regularmente se realiza en estos casos es validar si es numérico, en caso contrario entregar un valor default para evitar provoque un error tu app.

Comment: @RuslanLópez , es correto, gracias

Comment: @Root93 si datos.getOperacion() devuelve "01" con Long.parseLong(...) puedes obtener 1.

Answer (score 2):

Para convertir un `String` a `Long` lo realizas mediante `Long.parseLong()` como lo estas realizando, sin embargo el problema es que el valor `String` a convertir a `Long`, no es numérico.

Te sugiero evaluar si es numérico o no, en caso de no ser numérico puedes asignar un valor predeterminado, ejemplo 0, revisa el siguiente método:

```
public static long convertToLong(String strNum) {
    long valor;
    try {
        valor = Long.parseLong(strNum);
    } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
        return 0; //Valor default en caso de no poder convertir  a Long
    }
    return valor;
}
```

El método lo puedes usar de esta forma:

```
consulta.setNuOperacion(convertToLong(datos.getOperacion());
```

Answer (score 0):

El código esta bien lo que puedes hacer es revisar si datos.getOperacion() te esta retornando un valor númerico válido ya que la excepción me da a entender que no le estas mandando un valor correcto al Long.parseLog().